# AmazonSQSClient not refreshing AWSCredentials when Credentials File is updated

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, credentials

When my AWS Credentials File ([see docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html#creds-file)) is updated by an external process the AmazonSQSClient doesn't re-read it, SendMessageAsync fails with a security/token error.

We use a custom powershell script to refresh the local AWS cred's file periodically.  The script works fine, the file is refreshed prior to the credentials expiring on AWS.  However, if my app is running when the file is refreshed the new credentials are not re-read from the file, the "client" will show that the previous credentials are still in use.

The AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_Runtime_AWSCredentials.htm) list several AWSCredential providers but none of them seem to be the correct choice...*I think..*

Restarting the app works, the new credentials are read correctly and messages are sent until the next time the cred's file is updated.

```
using (var client = new AmazonSQSClient(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1))
{
    return client.SendMessageAsync(request);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works "ok" but I've only tested it with one profile and the file watcher is not as timely as you'd like so I'd recommend you wrap your usage inside a Retry mechanism.

```
// Usage..
var credentials = new AwsCredentialsFile();
using (var client = new AmazonSQSClient(credentials, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1))
{
    return client.SendMessageAsync(request);
}

public class AwsCredentialsFile : AWSCredentials
{
    // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html#creds-file

    private const string DefaultProfileName = "default";

    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, ImmutableCredentials> _credentials = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ImmutableCredentials>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    private static FileSystemWatcher _watcher = BuildFileSystemWatcher();

    private readonly System.Text.Encoding _encoding;

    private readonly string _profileName;

    public AwsCredentialsFile()
        : this(AwsCredentialsFile.DefaultProfileName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
    {
    }

    public AwsCredentialsFile(string profileName)
        : this(profileName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
    {
    }

    public AwsCredentialsFile(string profileName, System.Text.Encoding encoding)
    {
        _profileName = profileName;
        _encoding = encoding;
    }

    private static FileSystemWatcher BuildFileSystemWatcher()
    {
        var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
        {
            Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(GetDefaultCredentialsFilePath()),
            NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite,
            Filter = "credentials"
        };
        watcher.Changed += (object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) => { _credentials?.Clear(); };
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        return watcher;
    }

    public static string GetDefaultCredentialsFilePath()
    {
        return System.Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.aws\credentials");
    }

    public static (string AccessKey, string SecretAccessKey, string Token) ReadCredentialsFromFile(string profileName, System.Text.Encoding encoding)
    {
        var profile = $"[{profileName}]";
        string awsAccessKeyId = null;
        string awsSecretAccessKey = null;
        string token = null;

        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(GetDefaultCredentialsFilePath(), encoding);

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            var text = lines[i];
            if (text.Equals(profile, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                awsAccessKeyId = lines[i + 1].Replace("aws_access_key_id = ", string.Empty);
                awsSecretAccessKey = lines[i + 2].Replace("aws_secret_access_key = ", string.Empty);

                if (lines.Length >= i + 3)
                {
                    token = lines[i + 3].Replace("aws_session_token = ", string.Empty);
                }

                break;
            }
        }

        var result = (AccessKey: awsAccessKeyId, SecretAccessKey: awsSecretAccessKey, Token: token);
        return result;
    }

    public override ImmutableCredentials GetCredentials()
    {
        if (_credentials.TryGetValue(_profileName, out ImmutableCredentials value))
        {
            return value;
        }
        else
        {
            var (AccessKey, SecretAccessKey, Token) = ReadCredentialsFromFile(_profileName, _encoding);
            var credentials = new ImmutableCredentials(AccessKey, SecretAccessKey, Token);
            _credentials.TryAdd(_profileName, credentials);
            return credentials;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way for a running app to pick up the default credentials being refreshed in credentials file. There is a solution for Node.js [loading credentials from a JSON file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-json-file.html). You can create a similar solution in C#. You can also run a local DB to store credentials so whenever credentials file is updated DB table or JSON file is also updated. You will need to use `access key` and `secret key` in your SQS client constructor as opposed to using default credentials.

```
// Load these from JSON file or DB.
var accessKey = "";
var secretKey = "";

using (var client = new AmazonSQSClient(accessKey, secretKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1))
{
    return client.SendMessageAsync(request);
}
```

Comment: I was hoping there would be an AWS way I doing this I didn't know...thanks for ideas though.